# Animated splash screen with Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, splash-screen

Is that possible to add animated splash screens for Android and iOS Phonegap apps?
I tried to add animated .gif as splash screen file for Android but it doesn't work. I.e. there is no animation, the only thing I can see is first frame of the .gif.

And also is there a way to add dynamic text somewhere at splash screen? Actually this is what I want. And to use .gif is just my assumption how can I do it in the easiest way.
So, if you can give me example of working cod for iOS and Android dynamic splash screens with Phonegap it will be even better.

Answer (score 5):

gif animations are not supported on Android. Animations are possible using jQuery. This is what you can do

1. Create a data-role="page" div which contains your splash screen
   view
2. register a event listener for "pageshow" event for this page
   and start your animation using jQuery
3. In the same eventlistener call javascript's timeout function

`setTimeout('functionToLoadNewPage', 2000); 
//functionToLoadNewPage - function name which will load a new page using $.mobile.changePage and 2000 - number of milliseconds for splash screen to be visible`

Comment: But this page will show only when WebView loaded. I mean I need real splash screen that shows only while WebView loading. I can set up this splash by  super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", ...) (for Android), but I cannot make it animated in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching, and I think that you should create a javascript-android interface and do something like Cordova does.

This is the Cordova code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        String result = "";

         if (action.equals("hide")) {
             this.webView.postMessage("splashscreen", "hide");
         } else if (action.equals("show")){
             this.webView.postMessage("splashscreen", "show");
         }
         else {
             status = PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION;
         }
         return new PluginResult(status, result);
     }
```

And it is invoked throught javascript like this:

```
 exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "show", []);
```

Also you will need to do it for iOS too, see this link: [ios fade out splash screen (iphone 5 friendly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184448/ios-fade-out-splash-screen)

Comment: How does it help to add a text or animation to the splash screen?