# A notification popup, no action, ios

Tags: ios

I don't know the name of the UI Control, but in iOSthere is one way to show a splash screen that fades away after a determined time lapse. It's not the alertview because it doesn't take screen focus, just a splash screen showing some text. What is that called?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of this control? I can't think of any standard control that meets your description.

Comment: It's called do-it-yourself. Or perhaps you're looking for [toast](https://www.google.com/search?q=itoast&oq=itoast&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3.1131j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=ios+toast&oq=ios+toast&gs_l=serp.3...8673.8855.0.9118.3.3.0.0.0.2.296.555.2-2.2.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.rajKMVpKRa8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dGI&fp=4874ee7b20d8234d&biw=1163&bih=727).

Comment: maybe it is [ProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is something that people typically just create themselves. There is no specific, UI item that will do this for you. What you can do is just create a `ViewController` and have it be the foremost view on the screen when the app launches. And then have that `ViewController` initiate a timer that will countdown until it is time for it to fade out. Once this timer fires, you can start an animation to have it fade out (setting alpha to 0). And once that animation is completed, remove it from the screen.

That is what most people do. It is relatively easy to do and you could even probably find an example of it somewhere by googling around.

In fact, the first response when I googled ios splash screen was conveniently a stack overflow question, how peculiar

[ios fade out splash screen (iphone 5 friendly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184448/ios-fade-out-splash-screen-iphone-5-friendly)