# splashscreen during startup of Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, native, splash-screen

During startup of my Phonegap/Cordova application, I get a black screen for 3 seconds after which the webview comes to life. Is it possible to set a native splash-screen during these 3 seconds of black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yups

just add

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", getResId("splash", context, Drawable.class));
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

to your activity.
dont forget to add image splash to the res folder. :)

Comment: What should I fill context with?

Comment: If I try "getContext()" I get the error that that function is not defined for my Activity. If I simply do super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash) then I still get 3 seconds of black, only *then* the splashscreen and then my app.

Comment: Never mind,tThe super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash) works. Do you by any chance know how to make it animated? Can I use gifs?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481694/animated-splash-screen-with-phonegap

Comment: Yes, he asks the same question, but the answer is not satisfactionary. Still, plussed his question and I hope there will be answer :-) Thanks!